# Selecting only one radio button value in nested ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

Selecting only one of radio button values in nested ng-repeat.
Can you please suggest any wrong in source code

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
  <div ng-repeat="x in surveyLst">
    <div class="row">
      <br/>
      <span>{{$index+1}} .&nbsp; {{x.question}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="src in x.optnLst track by $index" ng-init='test=$index'>  
      <input type="radio" name={{$parent.$index+1}} ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-value="x.optnLst[test]" />  
      {{x.optnLst[test]}}  
    </div>
  </div>
  {{data}}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If you give the radios you want to group the same `name` attribute you get this behaviour for free without any JS required.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan i also declared same group name but not working. Can you check my source ?

Comment: Your code seems to working fine http://jsfiddle.net/nf2vxoza/

Comment: yes code is working http://jsfiddle.net/nf2vxoza/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nf2vxoza/

Comment: can you check jsfiddle  it is selecting 2 questions @jitender

Comment: $scope.surveyLst = [{question:'q1',optnLst:[1,2,3]},{question:'q2',optnLst:[1,2,3]}]
$scope.data=[];

Comment: please check this http://jsfiddle.net/prashanthhmie/nf2vxoza/2/

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `data.seletedOption` in `ng-model` set it to `x.seletedOption`

```
  <input type="radio" name={{$parent.$index+1}} ng-model="x.selectedOption" ng-value="x.optnLst[test]" />
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4egm9qh/)

Comment: Thank you @jitender its working...

Comment: @prashanth glad it helped you can mark this as accepted answer

Comment: i want send the selected radio button values to rest controller(spring) can you suggest the best way

Comment: how to store selected radio button values of all questions @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5621827/jitender